# Exposed filter in views to filter users by age

Tags: views

I have the Birthday module installed that displays the age of users. I am trying to create an exposed filter in a view that will allow users to select from $age1 to $age2. Of course this requires two filters (one min age and one max age) so the view will display all users who fall into that bracket. The Birthday module computes age "on the fly."
Any guidance on how to proceed with this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contextual range filter module](https://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter). to create a filter range for your age field.

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter, not just by a single value, but
>   also by range.
>
> Numeric, alphabetical (string) and list ranges are all supported. Node
>   ids, user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all special cases of
>   numbers so will work also. Range-filtering on the "created" (posted)
>   and "updated" (last modified) node properties is also supported,
>   provided you use the correct format as dictated by Views. So, YYYYMMDD
>   for full dates or one of the shorter year+month, year-only,
>   month-only, week-only and day-only formats.

Comment: It seems this is exactly what I need..! Thank you. :)